# Do std::optional and boost::optional respect alignment restrictions of the managed object?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-optional, stdoptional

If a class `T` has an alignment requirement, such as one specified by the `alignas` keyword, are `std::optional<T>` and `boost::optional<T>` guaranteed to respect said alignment?

If they were simply wrapper classes for a `T` object and a `bool initialized`, then they would automatically align their `T` member as required, but the standard and boost documentation state that they can hold no object and deal well with expensive to construct objects. From this I understand that they don't simply contain a `T`. Rather, they seem to allocate a buffer upon which the `T` is constructed or destroyed manually. Therefore, the C++ language will not automatically align the buffer because it is not of type `T`.

So, do `std::optional<T>` and `boost::optional<T>` properly align their managed `T` object? Do they also provide `optional<T>::operator new` and `optional<T>::operator new[]` that respect the alignment requirement?

Comment: ............yes.

Comment: Isn’t the answer *obviously* yes? I can’t imagine a non-broken implementation that doesn’t respect the template type’s alignment.

Comment: Why would they provide `operator new`?

Comment: Because the expression `new std::optional<T>` is not affected by the `alignas` specifier of `T` or of `std::optional<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A conforming implementation of std::optional *must* respect the alignment requirements of its `value_type` according to the C++17 standard draft:

> 23.6.3 Class template optional [optional.optional]
>
> (...)
>   The contained value shall be allocated in a region of the optional storage suitably aligned for the type T.

An implementor could use a union potentially containing the value as member, ensuring proper alignment.

As Thomas already mentioned while I was looking it up, boost::optional does ensure proper alignment by use of `aligned_storage<T>`

Comment: Thanks for finding this. cppreference.com didn't mention anything on alignment and I assumed it was actually unspecified by the standard. It is in paragraph 23.6.3 which you might want to mention in your post for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @patatahooligan: Thanks for the feedback, I added the heading to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the GNU C++ implementation, `std::optional` derives from `_Optional_Base<_Tp>`, which in turn contains an `_Optional_payload<_Tp>`. This is a template with several specializations, all of which contains the following members:

```
  using _Stored_type = remove_const_t<_Tp>;
  struct _Empty_byte { };
  union {
      _Empty_byte _M_empty;
      _Stored_type _M_payload;
  };
  bool _M_engaged = false;
```

As you can see, the `_M_payload` is actually strongly typed, so any alignment attributes should carry over properly in this implementation.

---

The Boost implementation does not use a union. Instead, `boost::optional<T>` derives from `optional_base<T>`, which simply contains:

```
 typedef aligned_storage<T> storage_type ;
 bool m_initialized ;
 storage_type m_storage ;
```

The name of `aligned_storage` is a clue; the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/aligned_storage.html) don't mention that the second template argument is optional and defaults to -1, which means `boost::detail::max_align`, which means to use the alignment a union type containing a bunch of primitive types up to 128 bits in length. So (from a cursory reading) Boost seems to be a bit more pessimistic than GNU, but will also get your alignment right.

Comment: I guess for the `boost` version, source code is adequate, but for the `std` version, I can't rely on specific implementations. I need a guarantee from the standard.